# Resource punkt not found. Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource: >>> import nltk >>> nltk.download('punkt')

Tags: python, import, error-handling

I have NLTK installed and it is going me error
Resource punkt not found.
Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

Attempted to load tokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle

Searched in:
- '/Users/divyanshundley/nltk_data'
- '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/nltk_data'
- '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/share/nltk_data'
- '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/nltk_data'
- '/usr/share/nltk_data'
- '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
- '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
- '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
- ''

---

and my code is

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')

def tokenize(token):
    return nltk.word_tokenize(token);
tokenize("why is this not working?");
```

Comment: Have you done what the error tells you?

Comment: yeah I have done the following :

Comment: pip install --user -U nltk

Comment: pip install --user -U numpy

Comment: The error tells you neither of those, it tells you to use `nltk.download('punkt')`

Comment: so , should I put nltk.download('punkt') in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please download the below also. This will resolve your issue:

```
*nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('wordnet')
nltk.download('omw-1.4'*
```

)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I simply find that punkt is just already in the directory:

> "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data\tokenizers"

However, the nklt module only tries to search

> "C:\Users\s1111\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data"

without the "tokenizers" directory.
So, just find the punky file in the first directory and copy it to the second directory. No need to download any files.

Answer (score 0):

**I was having the same issue, but the cause was different.**

I was getting an error message that punkt was missing but that wasn't the problem,the error message was a [bug](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2132)

The problem was that the language variable was placed on the wrong order on the method call.

If you need to use the preserve line parameter, make sure you assign a value to the language variable, since its a positional parameter.
A valid call of word_tokenize would be:

```
nltk.word_tokenize('My beautiful house is Awesome. My car is too.', language='english', preserve_line=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Executing these lines in Jupyter Notebook allowed me to tokenize successfully.

(Executing these lines launches the NLTK downloader)
`import nltk`
`nltk.download()`

From the menu I selected (d) Download then entered the "book" for the corpus to download, then (q) to quit.

(These lines then successfully tokenized the sentence)

`from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize`
`word_tokenize("Let's learn machine learning"`)

[Jupyter Notebook Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G492j.png)

[Jupyter Notebook Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Swrp.png)