# Resource punkt not found. In VENV

Tags: python

I have an application that uses ChatterBot - right now it's a simple conversation application. Anyway I started to use a VENV to start the app and now I have an issue with nltk

I'm not sure where in the app it's being used but when I try to run I get that error

```
 Resource punkt not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
```

here is my trace:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/chatterbot/jarvis.py", line 28, in <module>
    lessons.train([
  File "/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/chatterbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/chatterbot/trainers.py", line 103, in train
    statement_search_text = self.chatbot.storage.tagger.get_bigram_pair_string(text)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/chatterbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/chatterbot/tagging.py", line 135, in get_bigram_pair_string
    for sentence in self.tokenize_sentence(text.strip()):
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/chatterbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/chatterbot/tagging.py", line 68, in tokenize_sentence
    self.sentence_tokenizer = load_data('tokenizers/punkt/{language}.pickle'.format(
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/chatterbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 750, in load
    opened_resource = _open(resource_url)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/chatterbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 876, in _open
    return find(path_, path + [""]).open()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/grahammorby/Documents/GitHub/chatterbot/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 583, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource punkt not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
```

These are my sole Imports

```py
# Importing ChatterBot
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

# Import Google to text speech
import gtts
from playsound import playsound
```

I have also tried to install via PIP whilst in the venv but still pull the same error

Comment: what's the python version?

Comment: and what does 'Anyway I started to use a VENV to start the app and now I have an issue with nltk' mean? You weren't using venv before?

Comment: No I believe I was running it from PYTHON on windows before, it was some time ago

It is python3

Comment: Perhaps you should look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73744658/resource-punkt-not-found-please-use-the-nltk-downloader-to-obtain-the-resource and try the solutions there.

Comment: Yeah i tried that and no luck